# Interpolate between two UIFonts

Tags: ios, uiview, fonts, core-animation, uifont

Is it possible to find the average of two UIFonts? Lets say I have one font that was made with

```
[UIFont systemFontOfSize:11]
```

and another

```
[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15]
```

how would I find the average font of these two? I.e. it should be size 13 and only half bolded.

I'm looking for a solution that would let me linearly extrapolate at any point between the two. This is actually very similar to what an animation would do from one to the other, however, I'm not trying to do an animation.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

`UIFont` uses `pointSize` property. Using this we can get the average.

```
UIFont *font1 = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11];
UIFont *font2 = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];

CGFloat font1Size = font1.pointSize;
CGFloat font2Size = font2.pointSize;

CGFloat averageFontSize = (font1Size + font2Size) / 2;
NSLog(@"Average Font Size %f", averageFontSize);
```

It'll `NSLog` it as

```
Average Font Size 13.000000
```

Check [UIFont Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for properties.

Comment: Bit what about the bold? How do I get the average of the bold property? Wha

Comment: Ideally there is a generic solution for all properties of a font. Color, alpha, etc. How foes core animation do it when animating from one font to another?